# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 82: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, nltk

**Code:**

```
main_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(data)):
    print i
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    input_text = data['Input'][i].decode('latin-1', 'replace')
    input_text = re.sub(r'\\n',' ',input_text)
    pro_text = sub_fullstop(input_text)
    tok = token.tokenize(pro_text)
    tag = pdf_ner.tag(tok)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-77-1a4b40a73374>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/PurimetlaK.old/Documents/rohan/GPP_PDF_data preparation.py', wdir='C:/Users/PurimetlaK.old/Documents/rohan')

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:/Users/PurimetlaK.old/Documents/rohan/GPP_PDF_data preparation.py", line 53, in <module>
tag = pdf_ner.tag(tok)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 59, in tag
return self.tag_sents([tokens])[0]

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\stanford.py", line 82, in tag_sents
stanpos_output = stanpos_output.decode(encoding)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 82: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Some context might be helpful. Knowing what your doing/what you data is etc. makes it easier to help.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/dato-code/SFrame/issues/16#issuecomment-185326257

Comment: Run `file` on your input file to find the encoding. If it's in your control, tell your `open`er to use that encoding. Otherwise create an issue on GitHub.